# Android ViewModel not getting Selected Item from BackStackEntry

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have a map fragment that can be accessed from the bottom nav bar. I also want to be able to access it from a click on my recyclerview (if it is clicked from the recycler view, display the location from the recyclerview). To do this, I've attempted to check the backstack to see if the listfragment exists. I can't get it to work though, can someone see the issue with my code?

ViewModel:

```
    private final MutableLiveData<Fish> selected = new MutableLiveData<Fish>();

public void select(Fish item) {
    selected.setValue(item);
}

public LiveData<Fish> getSelected() {
    return selected;
}


public MapViewModel(Application application){
    super(application);
}
```

ListFragment(select is in onclick method):

```
mMapViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MapViewModel.class);
Log.d("view-click", String.valueOf(fish.getLocation()));

                mMapViewModel.select(fish);
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_fishListFragment_to_mapFragment2);
```

MapFragment:

```
NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
    NavBackStackEntry backStackEntry = navController.getBackStackEntry(R.id.fishListFragment);

    mMapViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(backStackEntry).get(MapViewModel.class);
    mMapViewModel.getSelected().observe(backStackEntry, list -> {
        Log.d("MAPFRAGMENT",list.getLocation() + "");
    });
```

I get no errors, but I also don't get the MAPFRAGMENT log in the logcat window. I've verified that my logcat is working, and that the onclick method is in fact setting the value in the viewmodel.

Comment: [SharedViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

Comment: I'm using a sharedviewmodel. I want to check the backstack to see where the user came from, if they came from the button I want to display the location from the list, and if not, I want to display their current location.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewModelProviders.of(this)` is associating the ViewModel with `this` - your Fragment itself, not the `NavBackStackEntry` (which is a whole separate layer above the Fragment layer).

Instead, you'll want to use `navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry()` with `new ViewModelProvider()` in your FishListFragment to associate the ViewModel with the `NavBackStackEntry` that you're later accessing in the MapFragment:

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
NavBackStackEntry currentBackStackEntry = navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry();
mMapViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(currentBackStackEntry).get(MapViewModel.class);
Log.d("view-click", String.valueOf(fish.getLocation()));

mMapViewModel.select(fish);
navController.navigate(R.id.action_fishListFragment_to_mapFragment2);
```

Comment: Thank you, that almost worked. If I load the mapfragment first from the bottomnav, and go back to the list fragment and then click the "go to location button", it will log the correct location. However, if I load the listfragment first and click the "go to location" button, it won't log the MAPFRAGMENT: Location log until I click bottomnav button for the list fragment. Any idea on why this is?